# Construct xml with variable node names in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, generics, for-xml

In my application I am running a rather complex query using `FOR XML PATH()` to construct an xml result. I am using this query in several stored procedures but each the root node and the first level node names are different. What I would like to do is create a scalar user defined function that takes the two node names as parameters and returns the correct xml. The expected output would look like this:

```
<{root node name}>
    <{first level node name}  attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
        <detail attr1="value3">
            <error code="1" descr="some error"/>
            <error code="3" descr="some other error"/>
        </detail>
    </{first level node name}>
    <error code="4" descr="yet another error"/>
</{root node name}>
```

With {root node name} and {first level node name} being passed as parameters

I know I can use dynamic SQL to do this but it can be very cumbersome and I would like to avoid it. I could also do it easily in C# or using XSLT but I need to do this entirely in SQL as it will be called from SQL Service broker handlers.

Unfortunately `FOR XML PATH` requires a literal for the node name. I also tried creating the xml with known generic node names and then trying to replace them using XQuery, but that also requires literals. Both the XQuery has to be a literal and the node names used in node constructors need to be literals as well (cannot use `sql:variable()`)

Is there any way create XML with dynamic node names?

Comment: "I know I can use dynamic SQL to do this" Not in a user defined function.... I'm afraid the only two options I'm aware of to do it on the database level are CLR or dynamic SQL (in a stored procedure, not a UDF).

Comment: True, but doing it in a UDF is only a convenience not a requirement. I can turn it into a stored procedure returning a single column resultset, or use output parameters.

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further assistance?

Comment: Not really. I ended up coding the UDF to use generic element names and then manipulate the xml using xquery outside of the UDF where the element names are known, so the xquery can be a literal. I do have to repeat the xquery everywhere I use the function which is an annoyance and error prone. As far as I am aware of, it is either this (when possible) or dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As the elements names are built out of the result set's column names this cannot work (other than dynamic SQL or CLR), but there is rescue:

```
DECLARE @rowName NVARCHAR(10)=N'TheRow';
DECLARE @rootName NVARCHAR(10)=N'TheRoot';

DECLARE @OutputXml XML=
CAST(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(
    CAST((SELECT TOP 2 [name],[type] 
          FROM sys.objects 
          FOR XML PATH(N'ThisIsAStringOnlyUsedAsRowElementName')
                 ,ROOT(N'TheSameIdeaForTheRootName')
                 ,TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    ,N'ThisIsAStringOnlyUsedAsRowElementName',@rowName)
    ,N'TheSameIdeaForTheRootName',@rootName) AS XML);


SELECT @outputXML;
```

The result

```
<TheRoot>
  <TheRow>
    <name>spt_fallback_db</name>
    <type>U </type>
  </TheRow>
  <TheRow>
    <name>spt_fallback_dev</name>
    <type>U </type>
  </TheRow>
</TheRoot>
```

In general I'd avoid string manipulations on an XML (due to possible side effects and performance impact). But I think this is a legit workaround...

Comment: Double casting and a double replace... this might suffer from performance issues if it's a long XML, but it's a nice workaround, though... +1.